# Set pipe inside sch-40 PVC to use as post for sun shade

Tags: concrete, pipe, pvc, anchor

Years ago I put a 2" O.D. 20' flagpole inside a 2" sch-40 PVC pipe which was set in concrete.  The 2" flagpole fit perfectly inside the PVC and it has been through 50-60 mph winds and never waivers.
I want to use the same idea on a smaller scale to anchor the third point of a triangular sun shade in the back yard.  So far I've used the galvanized top pipe inside an 1 1/2 PVC pipe, but there is way too much size difference for that to work.  The galvanized pipe is 1 5/16 O.D. and the PVC is 1 9/16 I.D., so that leaves about 1/8" of air all the way around the galvanized pipe.  Anybody know a good match for the O.D of a galvanized pipe and the I.D. of a PVC pipe?

Comment: Sun shades tend to act more like sails/parachutes in the wind compared to flags.  Posts used for them need to stronger and more anchored than flag poles.  I would not trust PVC to hold a steel pipe down, even if bolted together.

Comment: I did some looking around in my garage and found an 1 7/8" O.D. galvanized pipe that was previously used to mount a traffic light.  Actually I have two 3' 10" sections which are threaded at one end.  I plan to use a threaded connector to create a 7' 8" pipe which will fit into the 2" PVC with 1/16" space around the pipe.  Not a perfect fit, but I'm hoping I can put at least a foot and a half in concrete and that should be stable enough for a 9' triangular sail.
What do you think?

Comment: But traffic lights don't see the same wind loads as a sail.

Comment: In case you're wondering how many pounds of force you can expect on your sail, [here's one calculator](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Wind-Load) that will tell you. If you don't like those numbers, an internet search for "calculate force of wind against a surface" will bring up a dozen other calculators. (That just happened to be the first response - no endorsement or guarantee of accuracy.)

Comment: The one thing that I don't see addressed is how _deep_ you're putting these pipes in the ground. 18" deep probably won't hold your sail in anything more than a light breeze. 60" deep and you'll probably be fine.

Answer (score 0):

LMGTFY: [Here is a table of PVC sizes.](https://www.pvcfittingsonline.com/resource-center/pvc-pipe-dimensions-18-through-24/)

From that table:

Nominal PVC size: 1-1/4"
Outer diameter: 1.660"
Inner diameter: 1.360"

1-5/16" = 1.3125". That leaves a gap of 0.0475", divided by 2 is 0.02375", which is a pretty tight fit.

But rather than rely on published dimensions, I would take a piece of the galvanized pipe to a big box store (which may be easier but will have less selection) or a plumbing supply house and check it on some actual PVC pipe.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers/suggestions.  After finding some larger pipe around the house I decided that was a better way to go.
One thing I never mentioned is that my reasoning for putting the galvanized pipe inside the PVC and cutting it off at ground level is to allow me to take it down in the fall and then put it back up again in the spring/summer.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a piece of the plastic pipe but cutting an axial strip out of it so it can be compressed to fit inside the outer pipe like a sleeve - that should take up the extra space.